# In php, what is a good way to determine whether private property is set?

Tags: php, private, isset

Consider the following user class:

```
<?php

class User
{
    private string $name;

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

$user = new User();
```

We would like to get the `$name` property of object `$user`. However, the `$name` property has not always been set. If we run `$user->getName()` and the `$name` property has not been set, then we get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Typed property User::$name must not be accessed before initialization
```

How can we call `$user->getName()` without running into errors?

**Use `__isset`?**

Should we use the `__isset` magic method? For example, we could add the following `__isset` method to the class:

```
public function __isset($name): bool {
    return isset($this->$name);
}
```

And then, from outside the class, we could run:

```
if (isset($user->name)) {
    // $user->getName() can now be called
}
```

However, it seems odd that our code would contain `$user->name` knowing in advance that the `$name` property is private. Also, since we call the `$name` property often, we would be adding this `if` statement in numerous (perhaps hundreds of) places in our code.

**Default `$name` to be null?**

For example, we could update our class:

```
class User
{
    private ?string $name = null;

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then, from outside the class, we could run:

```
if (isset($user->getName())) {
    // Do stuff ...
}
```

However, it seems odd that `$name` would default to `null` since `null` is not a valid value for someone's name. An "uninitialized" value seems more appropriate. And, we would again need to add numerous `if` statements around our code.

Any suggestions or feedback would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Simple solution would be to enforce that a valid (how you define valid is up to you) `name` is provided via the `Users` constructor.

Comment: Null is commonly used to represent an unknown value, so it's a reasonable option.

Comment: @Peppermintology Thank you. However, our business logic does not guarantee that the `$name` property is set. Also, `$name` is just an example. The same question would apply for any other optional properties such as `$nickname` or `$city`, etc.

Comment: @LeoGalleguillos Are you unable to modify the `User` to require these properties via the constructor? Or do you mean that for whatever reason, you're not always provided with data for certain properties you use with a `User`?

Comment: @Peppermintology We are not always provided with data for certain properties that we use with a `User`. Also, from outside of the class, we cannot be certain that the property has been initialized, regardless of the reason.

Comment: What do the other parts of your system that use the `get` methods of a `User` do with their return value? For example do they have scenarios where the value is either `null` or an `empty` string?

Comment: Keep things simple and just have getName return this: ```$this->name ?? '';```

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding the use of conditional checks throughout your system could be difficult as it appears your system expects `valid` values but these are not always available and, depending on how the places your `getters` are called use the return value.

If your `User` is open to some modification, then you could as you've suggested make certain properties nullable or initialize them with suitable values (`null`, `empty`, whatever works for your business/use case). As [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren) has mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74910560/in-php-what-is-a-good-way-to-determine-whether-private-property-is-set#comment132197897_74910560) a `null` value can be perfectly valid depending on the scenario (although it might not be ideal).

The following might be helpful to you, although it doesn't entirely mitigate the requirement to perform conditional checks. It does provide some (arguably) easier helper methods for performing such checks and returning some default values.

```
class User
{
    private ?string $name = null;
    
    private ?string $nickname = '';
    
    private ?string $city = 'New York';
    
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name !== null && !empty($this->name) 
            ? $this->name 
            : "Not Provided";
    }
    
    public function getNickName()
    {
        return $this->nickname !== null && !empty($this->nickname) 
            ? $this->nickname
            : "Not Provided";
    }
    
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city !== null && !empty($this->city) 
            ? $this->city
            : "Not Provided";
    }
    
    public function uninitialised()
    {
        $uninitialized = [];
        foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $property => $value) {
            if (!isset($value) || empty($value)) {
                $uninitialized[] = $property;
            }
        }
        
        return $uninitialized;
    }
    
    public function checkForUninitialised(array $properties)
    {
        return array_intersect($properties, $this->uninitialised());
    }
}

$user = new User();

var_dump($user->uninitialised());

echo PHP_EOL;

var_dump(
    $user->checkForUninitialised(
        ['name', 'nickname', 'city'], 
        $user->uninitialised()
    )
);
```

The output of the above would be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "nickname"
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "nickname"
}
```

Comment: Too much "repeating yourself" code here, at this point you might as well use the magic ```__get()```. Nevertheless this code removes the type return values in the original post.

Comment: @Robert Indeed. It's just an illistrative example following the pattern OP has used. We also don't know where in the rest of the system, or external systems, the `getProperty` methods are used. It may not be possible to refactor for `__get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Four ways come to my mind:

- Initialize $name upon definition
- Force the constructor to initialize $name
- Check within `getName()`
- Add a helper method

```
class User
{
    // either pre-initialize
    private string $name = '';

    // or enforce setting by constructor
    public function __construct(string $name = '')
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        // or check within getName(), null-coalescing operator added as suggested by Robert in a comment
            return $this->name ?? '';
        }
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    // or add a public helper function
    public function isNameSet(): bool
    {
        return (isset($this->name));
    }


}

$user = new User();

if ($user->isNameSet()) {
    // Do things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-typed property, or initialize it in the constructor, or with the declaration of the property.

The whole point or a typed property is to avoid comparison with null (well, one of the points). Also null is not a string. So using a null/or-string **type** defeates the whole point more or less - you may just as well use a non-typed property instead.

> In php, what is a good way to determine whether private property is set?

You have the wrong frame of mind imho. In the OOP paradigm, it's your responsibility to initialize your objects properly, as opposed to *asking* "are my objects initialized propery?" after instantiation.

So the answer is: initialize it properly, or declare a default value.

GLHF

Comment: Typed property with empty or null value could be used as @Peppermintology suggested

Comment: @DmitryK. yes, but ask yourself: If you are writing new code, why would you want something to be null or string and not always string? From experience and intuition my feeling is that you don't. I invite you (and other readers) to think about this in relation to object instantiation, validation, null pointer exceptions (or de-referencing properties on null), value objects and just plain comparison operations. Also.. I already concede it could be used, but my argument is that it's (almost) pointless to do so.